# Saving a list of reviewers in Gerrit?

Tags: r, gerrit

Gerrit 2.13.8-4-gb79a18cfff-dirty

I just joined a new project.

Every time I push committed code to Gerrit I need to manually feed it a list of reviewers for my ticket/issue.

Is there any way I can save this list in Gerrit or does the owner of the project need to do that ( how? )

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For server/project administrators, Gerrit offers several plugins to add add adding reviewers automatically, e.g. [reviewers](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/reviewers/).

For you as a user, you can set a push option to set a reviewer on push time. See [my Q&A on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48319220/1254292) on how to configure that for every push by default.